# Laravel: Form model binding and resource controller error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a really simple CRUD in laravel just to learn something about this framework. 
It works all like a charm but I can't make the update function of a controller work properly.

Here my situation:

**1)** I build a resource controller using artisan command.

**2)** I build a form view using blade and I Open the form with this code:

```
<!-- Form -->
@if($mode=="edit")
    {{ Form::model($task, array('route'=>array('task.update',$task->id),'files'=>true)) }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(array('route'=>'task.store','files'=>true)) }}
@endif
```

It works great and every field are filled with the right data.
The generate url of the **form's action** is:

```
http://localhost/mysite/task/2
```

The problem is that when I submit this form I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Someone can understand why? Can I help you with more information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 'method' => 'put'.

`{{ Form::model($task, array('route' => array('task.update', $task->id), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT')) }}`

As you can see here.

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

```
Verb:     PUT/PATCH
Path:     /resource/{id}
action:   update
route:    resource.update
```

EDIT: To trigger the update()-action you must send a PUT or PATCH-request to the route `resource.update`, in your case `task.update`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the form action. Assuming you have a route like this:

```
Route::post('task/update/{id}, function()
{

});
```

Then, your model-bound form should be:

```
{{ Form::model($task, array('url'=>array('task/update',$task->id),'files'=>true)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only error in your code is that you did not passed PUTor PATCH as HTTP method for your form submission to server.

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException is triggered on such states.

a demo model form will be as

```
 Form::model($name_model, array('action' => array('Controller_name@method', $argument), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT'))
```

or with route name as

```
Form::model($name_model, array('route' => array('route.name', $argument), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT'))
```